# Can we use COM objects in C# project?

Tags: c#, com

I have made a C# COM object by following the tutorial.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18939/C-Com

Now I want to use this in C#. When I go to add reference \ com \ myComObject it gives me error. It says that the library was imported from a .NET assembly and cannot be added. Add a reference to the .NET assembly instead.

Comment: If it is not an exercise, you would better use the C# object as is in the other c# project, avoiding the COM layer at all.

Comment: yes. I added dll file in reference instead of adding COM object reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is saying it is a com visible .net assembly and you should add the .net assembly directly as a .net assenbly.  The technique you link to is how to write a .net assemby that can be referenced from VB6.  There is no need to add this as a com reference to a .net project, just add it as a normal .net reference.

Comment: yes. I added dll file in reference instead of adding COM object reference.