# Writing COM object in C# and using it from C#

Tags: c#, com, .net

I would like to implement a COM object in C# and also use it in C# (besides C++ and others).

Here is the code of the DLL implementing the COM object :

```
namespace TestComServer {
  [ComVisible(true),
  Guid("565D8202-6C0F-4AAB-B0F6-49719CD13045"),
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
  ]
  public interface ITestObject {
    void DoSomething();
  }

  [
  ComVisible(true),
  GuidAttribute("21293767-A713-49E2-968E-7DDE0B0DAB94"),
  ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
  ]
  public class TestObject : ITestObject {
    public TestObject() {
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
    }
  }
}
```

I've used gacutil at add the DLL to the global assembly cache.

The EXE uses the COM object in the following way (like I successfully did with some COM objects implemented in C++):

```
[
ComImport(),
Guid("565D8202-6C0F-4AAB-B0F6-49719CD13045"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
]
public interface ITestObject {
  [PreserveSig ]
  void DoSomething();
}

[ComImport, Guid("21293767-A713-49E2-968E-7DDE0B0DAB94")]
public class TestObject {
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  object o = new TestObject();
  ITestObject t = (ITestObject)o;
  t.DoSomething();
}
```

When executing the line *object o = new TestObject();*, I get an InvalidCastException. What is wrong with this code?

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Test.exe
>   Additional information: Das Objekt des Typs "TestComServer.TestObject" kann nicht in Typ "TestObject" umgewandelt werden.

Comment: Did you forget to have TestObject inherit from ITestObject?

Comment: Did you register the assembly as a COM object in the registry using  regasm? regasm YourDll.dll /tlb

Comment: In the DLL implementation, I've inherited from ITestObject. In the EXE I cannot do that because I don't implement ITestObject, I would like to use the DLLs implementation like I did that with many C++ COM objects before.

Comment: I've checked the "Register for COM interop" checkbox in the Visual Studio project properties of the DLL. This should call regasm, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we use COM objects in C# project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394133/can-we-use-com-objects-in-c-sharp-project)

Comment: Similar questions seem to indicate that a C#-defined COM object can only be used in a C# project as a .NET object, not through COM.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9394133/385844 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1482131/385844

Comment: Explicitely calling regasm doesn't make any difference. I've just tried it.

I've tried an alternative implementation of the EXE using the Win32 CoCreateInstance function: CoCreateInstance succeeds, but when I want to cast the returned object to ITestObject, I get the same exception again.

Comment: phoog, thanks for your links. This could be the problem indeed. Is there really no way to use C# COM objects in C#?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be of much more help; my knowledge of COM interop is not deep enough to know if there would be some way to fool the marshaller into marshalling the C# object to COM and back. If your objective is to test a C# COM server, perhaps the answer is to write the tests in native C++ or another non-managed COM-capable language.  If your objective is to consume COM-visible C# types in a .NET application, then obviously the answer is just to use the assemblies directly as managed assemblies.  Or is your objective something else?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the EXE so that it only imports the interface, then instantiate the object using Type.GetTypeFromCLSID and Activator.CreateInstance:

```
[
ComImport(),
Guid("565D8202-6C0F-4AAB-B0F6-49719CD13045"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
]
public interface ITestObject {
  [PreserveSig ]
  void DoSomething();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Type type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("21293767-A713-49E2-968E-7DDE0B0DAB94"));
  object o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  ITestObject t = (ITestObject)o;
  t.DoSomething();
}
```

I've not used that method of importing COM objects before, so this might not work. Generally I define my interfaces in a separate assembly that is also exposed to COM that is then referenced by both the DLL and the EXE. The EXE instantiates the DLL using the above method and casts it to the .NET interface that it has referenced.